# No space device left tensorflow docker cloud shell with buildpacks

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform

I got this error after I run this script:

```
#/bin/bash

# Build Image
pack build deepcare_image --builder gcr.io/buildpacks/builder:v1 --path . &&

# Push to GCR
gcloud auth configure-docker &&
docker tag deepcare_image:latest gcr.io/deep-care-capstone/deepcare_image:latest &&
docker push gcr.io/deep-care-capstone/deepcare_image:latest &&

# Deploy to CloudRun
gcloud run deploy deepcare-api --image gcr.io/deep-care-capstone/deepcare_image:latest
```

Returning error:

```
v1: Pulling from buildpacks/builder
Running "python3 -m pip check"
No broken requirements found.
Adding 1/1 app layer(s)
Adding layer 'buildpacksio/lifecycle:launcher'
Timer: Saving deepcare_image39876... started at 2023-12-21T21:46:59Z
*** Images (983d9eff9e4d):
      deepcare_image39876 - loading image "deepcare_image39876". first error: embedded daemon response: write /layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/libtensorflow_cc.so.2: no space left on device
Timer: Saving deepcare_image39876... ran for 1m18.845016348s and ended at 2023-12-21T21:48:18Z
Timer: Exporter ran for 1m34.264716144s and ended at 2023-12-21T21:48:18Z
ERROR: failed to export: failed to write image to the following tags: [deepcare_image39876: loading image "deepcare_image39876". first error: embedded daemon response: write /layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/libtensorflow_cc.so.2: no space left on device]
ERROR: failed to build: executing lifecycle: failed with status code: 62
```

I have no idea what to do, I tried to clean VM state but it was doing nothing.

Note that, previously it was fine when last I tried to run the script.

Update, here is output `df -ah`:

```
root@cs-179510100035-default:/home/c315bsy3271/deep-care-api# df -ah
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay                            114G  106G  8.1G  93% /
proc                                  0     0     0    - /proc
tmpfs                               64M     0   64M   0% /dev
devpts                                0     0     0    - /dev/pts
mqueue                                0     0     0    - /dev/mqueue
sysfs                                 0     0     0    - /sys
cgroup                                0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                          114G  106G  8.1G  93% /root
/dev/disk/by-id/google-home-part1  4.8G  192M  4.4G   5% /home
/dev/sda1                          114G  106G  8.1G  93% /etc/hostname
/dev/root                          2.0G  1.1G  849M  57% /lib/modules
/dev/sda1                          114G  106G  8.1G  93% /etc/hosts
/dev/sda1                          114G  106G  8.1G  93% /etc/resolv.conf
shm                                 64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1                          114G  106G  8.1G  93% /var/config/shared-secret
/dev/sda1                          114G  106G  8.1G  93% /etc/ssh/keys
/dev/sda1                          114G  106G  8.1G  93% /var/config/tmux
/dev/sda1                          114G  106G  8.1G  93% /var/lib/docker
/dev/sda1                          114G  106G  8.1G  93% /run/google/devshell
tmpfs                              3.2G  808K  3.2G   1% /google/host/var/run
ramfs                                 0     0     0    - /google/host/var/run/credentials/systemd-sysctl.service
ramfs                                 0     0     0    - /google/host/var/run/credentials/systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
ramfs                                 0     0     0    - /google/host/var/run/credentials/systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
ramfs                                 0     0     0    - /google/host/var/run/credentials/systemd-resolved.service
nsfs                                  0     0     0    - /google/host/var/run/netns/cni-a9f3920c-2960-a1bc-b258-4c98b67f50f9
shm                                 64M     0   64M   0% /google/host/var/run/containerd/io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri/sandboxes/bfa4c8c06ddcd3a48047a8a7d353778eeec9c51a2f2aab919c88857c9420e449/shm
nsfs                                  0     0     0    - /google/host/var/run/netns/cni-8bdcebbb-d416-5cd8-139c-fb7f8a214316
gcfsd                              0.0K  0.0K  0.0K    - /google/host/var/run/gcfsd/mnt
overlay                            114G  106G  8.1G  93% /google/host/var/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/bfa4c8c06ddcd3a48047a8a7d353778eeec9c51a2f2aab919c88857c9420e449/rootfs
overlay                            114G  106G  8.1G  93% /google/host/var/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/111311c054717bf3571411c079cf7d7b01c508957985e7eb920531035f7e53a0/rootfs
shm                                 64M     0   64M   0% /google/host/var/run/containerd/io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri/sandboxes/02b66ae35c39a39276841a435b7641f358ff6ff8eadd8715b8ac8b4b22dc5c78/shm
nsfs                                  0     0     0    - /google/host/var/run/netns/cni-f1b6175d-4963-4c32-f897-1ffa38f60ae7
overlay                            114G  106G  8.1G  93% /google/host/var/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/02b66ae35c39a39276841a435b7641f358ff6ff8eadd8715b8ac8b4b22dc5c78/rootfs
overlay                            114G  106G  8.1G  93% /google/host/var/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/5c915f9007228f47a4a9f57772f195223a6482ff05ab1919f4152b4ac83c6cb5/rootfs
overlay                            114G  106G  8.1G  93% /google/host/var/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/d6244b37b4ef9d4c2cd59d5d210159860933baa5acf24cab5c2dc7c11ca139e5/rootfs
overlay                            114G  106G  8.1G  93% /google/host/var/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/d6244b37b4ef9d4c2cd59d5d210159860933baa5acf24cab5c2dc7c11ca139e5/rootfs
proc                                  0     0     0    - /google/host/var/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/d6244b37b4ef9d4c2cd59d5d210159860933baa5acf24cab5c2dc7c11ca139e5/rootfs/proc
tmpfs                               64M     0   64M   0% /google/host/var/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/d6244b37b4ef9d4c2cd59d5d210159860933baa5acf24cab5c2dc7c11ca139e5/rootfs/dev
devpts                                0     0     0    - /google/host/var/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/d6244b37b4ef9d4c2cd59d5d210159860933baa5acf24cab5c2dc7c11ca139e5/rootfs/dev/pts
mqueue                                0     0     0    - /google/host/var/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/d6244b37b4ef9d4c2cd59d5d210159860933baa5acf24cab5c2dc7c11ca139e5/rootfs/dev/mqueue
shm                                 64M     0   64M   0% /google/host/var/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/d6244b37b4ef9d4c2cd59d5d210159860933baa5acf24cab5c2dc7c11ca139e5/rootfs/dev/shm
sysfs                                 0     0     0    - /google/host/var/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/d6244b37b4ef9d4c2cd59d5d210159860933baa5acf24cab5c2dc7c11ca139e5/rootfs/sys
cgroup                                0     0     0    - /google/host/var/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/d6244b37b4ef9d4c2cd59d5d210159860933baa5acf24cab5c2dc7c11ca139e5/rootfs/sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                          114G  106G  8.1G  93% /google/host/var/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/d6244b37b4ef9d4c2cd59d5d210159860933baa5acf24cab5c2dc7c11ca139e5/rootfs/root
/dev/disk/by-id/google-home-part1  4.8G  192M  4.4G   5% /google/host/var/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/d6244b37b4ef9d4c2cd59d5d210159860933baa5acf24cab5c2dc7c11ca139e5/rootfs/home
/dev/sda1                          114G  106G  8.1G  93% /google/host/var/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/d6244b37b4ef9d4c2cd59d5d210159860933baa5acf24cab5c2dc7c11ca139e5/rootfs/etc/hostname
/dev/root                          2.0G  1.1G  849M  57% /google/host/var/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/d6244b37b4ef9d4c2cd59d5d210159860933baa5acf24cab5c2dc7c11ca139e5/rootfs/lib/modules
/dev/sda1                          114G  106G  8.1G  93% /google/host/var/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/d6244b37b4ef9d4c2cd59d5d210159860933baa5acf24cab5c2dc7c11ca139e5/rootfs/etc/hosts
/dev/sda1                          114G  106G  8.1G  93% /google/host/var/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/d6244b37b4ef9d4c2cd59d5d210159860933baa5acf24cab5c2dc7c11ca139e5/rootfs/etc/resolv.conf
/dev/sda1                          114G  106G  8.1G  93% /google/host/var/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/d6244b37b4ef9d4c2cd59d5d210159860933baa5acf24cab5c2dc7c11ca139e5/rootfs/var/config/shared-secret
/dev/sda1                          114G  106G  8.1G  93% /google/host/var/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/d6244b37b4ef9d4c2cd59d5d210159860933baa5acf24cab5c2dc7c11ca139e5/rootfs/etc/ssh/keys
/dev/sda1                          114G  106G  8.1G  93% /google/host/var/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/d6244b37b4ef9d4c2cd59d5d210159860933baa5acf24cab5c2dc7c11ca139e5/rootfs/var/config/tmux
/dev/sda1                          114G  106G  8.1G  93% /google/host/var/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/d6244b37b4ef9d4c2cd59d5d210159860933baa5acf24cab5c2dc7c11ca139e5/rootfs/var/lib/docker
/dev/sda1                          114G  106G  8.1G  93% /google/host/var/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/d6244b37b4ef9d4c2cd59d5d210159860933baa5acf24cab5c2dc7c11ca139e5/rootfs/run/google/devshell
none                                  0     0     0    - /sys/kernel/security
```

Comment: /tensorflow/libtensorflow_cc.so.2: no space left on device, is your harddisk full?

Comment: Resize the VM's persistent disk. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/resize-persistent-disk

Comment: @JohnHanley But I'm using **cloudshell**

Comment: Cloud Shell has a hard limit of 5 GB. That cannot be changed. https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/how-cloud-shell-works#persistent_disk_storage The output from `df -ah` is not from Cloud Shell. Why did you include that information?

Comment: but that output `df -ah` from cloud shell

Comment: You are displaying the host's partitions. Cloud Shell is a container running on the host. The only space you can use/consume is `/home`

Comment: @JohnHanley sure for the write operation but not really for read operation.

Comment: I do not understand why you felt the need to comment about read operations. Your problem is running out of free disk space.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to explore options to mount external storage volumes, such as [Google Cloud Storage buckets](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/buckets), to expand your available space.